# Infinite loading while installing joomla 2.5.1

Tags: joomla, installation

I have had worked on joomla 1.5 last year but today while installing joomla 2.5.1 I got infinite loading on filling form for step 4:Database.
Any help please

Answer (score 1):

1. This is because Joomla is unable to connect to your database, check your database connection information: username, password and database name
2. I usually create the database beforehand to avoid any issues creating the database.
3. Are you using the default user root with a blank password?
4. If you are on Windows 7, you may need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: About "I usually create the database beforehand to avoid any issues creating the database." I did the same
About "Are you using the default user root with a blank password?" Yes
About "If you are on Windows 7, you may need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost" Ya I am using window 7 ultimate, tried 127.0.0.1 but no change

Comment: What *AMP are you using WAMP, XAMP or your own custom installation of Apache, PHP, and MySQL? What versions of Apache, PHP and MySQL are you running?

Comment: Is your database running? Start Wamp Server -> MySQL -> MySQL Console. It will prompt you for a password then hit enter (since the password is blank), if you get an access denied error then it may be that. You may also try going to phpmyadmin via http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin to see if you can access the database name that you are using

Comment: ya its running and the db have all joomla tables in it. Whats going wrong then :(

Comment: You may want to delete all the existing Joomla tables from the failed installations, I think its trying to back them up before it installs a new set of tables

Comment: I haven't check the backup db option. I emptied the db and also tried it with newly created db but no change.